# Java - Iterate over many files and folders

Tags: java, file-io, iteration

I want to iterate over really many files which are placed in a deep folder hierarchy. 
The files in question are 15 GB of MS Word documents I intend to process with POI. POI works fine, but a simple recursive function creates an OutOfMemoryException:

```
public void checkDir(File dir) {
    for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (".".equals(child.getName()) || "..".equals(child.getName()))
            continue; // Ignore the self and parent aliases.
        if (child.isFile())
            processFile(child); // do something
        else if (child.isDirectory())
            checkDir(child);
    }
}

// check if the word file can be read by POI
private void processFile(File file) {
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    WordExtractor extractor = null;

    try {
        extractor = new WordExtractor(in);
        extractor.getText();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This can happen if the file has the "doc" extension, but is
        // not a Word document
        throw new Exception(file + "is not a doc");
    } finally {
        in.close();
        in = null;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // log the error to a file
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter("corruptFiles.txt", true);
        fw.write(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\r\n");
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
        }
    }       
}
```

Trying to accomplish this with `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles` yields the same exception:

```
String[] extensions = { "doc" };

Iterator<File> iter = FileUtils.iterateFiles(dir, extensions, true);
for(; iter.hasNext();)
{
    File file = iter.next();
    processFile(file); // do something
}
```

I am running Java 6 on Windows 7 and not allowed to move or rearrange the files.

What are my options?

Thank you for your time.

[EDIT] Added the processFile function. Just did a successful run with a simplified version of processFile after increasing the heap size to 512 MB.
In conclusion my problem is somehow POI related and NOT to iterating files.

```
private void processFile(File file) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

[EDIT2] I could narrow the cause of the exception down to a 33 MB file. Trying to parse that results in the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception. I will post a ticket to the POI bug tracker. Thanks everybody for your suggestions.
I'll accept MathAsmLang's answer as that helped to overcome the iteration problem.
I would have accepted krishnakumarp's comment as an answer, as he was the first one to point that out, but that proved to be impossible ;-)

Comment: How much memory you've allocated to the VM? Please try increasing it using -Xmx -Xms options.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the "do something" part you don't show us. If it keeps a reference to some or all the file data loaded so far, you will quickly run out of memory indeed. Try running VisualVM to detect what consumes your memory.

Comment: I would suspect that processFile is leaking memory more than the recursion over files.

Comment: A simple way to test whether processFile is the cause; comment it out and re-run the program.

Comment: Maybe we can help if you post more about the `processFile(file)`

Comment: Just did a successful run with a simplified version of processFile after increasing the heap size to 512 MB.
In conclusion my problem is somehow POI related and NOT to iterting files. 
Should I delete the question or accept the answer from MathAsmLang as the increasing of the heap size helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is outofmemoryerror, you should try out starting jvm with
different memory parameters i.e. heap size.